# Why isn't the variable being updated and returned correctly in this function?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, return-value

So I've been following a video and Google's documentation trying to implement user sign in with Firebase on an android app. Which is working, so to try and tidy up (and help me reuse the code in another project) I have alot of the sign in code moved to a seperate .kt file and used the below funcion to create a new user.

```
//in LoginActivity.kt
fun createNewUser(email:String, password:String) :Boolean{
        var success:Boolean = false

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    
                    success = true
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(null, "createUserWithEmail:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    //updateUI(user)
                    
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(null, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                    //Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    //updateUI(null)
                    success = false
                }               
            }

        return success
    }
```

The issue I am having is that the "success" boolean isn't being updated when the account is created, the Log saying "success" appears to run fine. I tried changing the inital state of `success` from `false` to `true` and that returned `true` as expected and my code looking at the result of this ran fine.

Here is where its being called from, as I said the toasts run fine but the value of `success` returned is always what it was initialised as.

```
//in MainActivity.kt
var login = LoginActivity()
            if(login.createNewUser(email,password)) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"I got this far",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                uploadImageToFirebase()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"I didnt get this far",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start at the end, because this is a huge mistake:

```
var login = LoginActivity()
```

Never instantiate an Activity. Activity instantiation is handled by the operating system. If `createNewUser` relies on any functions of `LoginActivity`, then it will fail when called on your own instantiated instance. And if it doesn't rely on them, then don't define it inside `LoginActivity`.

Regarding your main question:

When you pass a callback to a function, that means it runs asynchronously. The callback will be called some time in the future, after this function has already returned. So `createNewUser` can't return the result of the callback.

Instead, you can create your own callback for your function like this. I'm treating `auth.currentUser` as type `User`, but you should put whatever class it actually is.

```
fun createNewUser(email:String, password:String, onComplete: (User?) -> Unit) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(null, "createUserWithEmail:success")
                    onComplete(auth.currentUser)
                    
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(null, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                    onComplete(null)
                }               
            }
    }
```

Then to use it, you can call the function and in your lambda callback you can react based on whether the user is null or not, which indicates failure or success:

```
createNewUser(email, password) { user ->
    if (user != null) {
        // success. Do something with the smart-casted non-null user variable
    } else {
        // failure. Show error message to the user, etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this I'll kep all this in mind and head back to the documentation and video because I was trying to essentiall make what they had more modular but clearly this wasnt the best idea. I especially like how your checked for success because while I figured a Boolean wasn't the best idea I was drawing a blank on what else to us.